# Why is there an 'h' at the end of the word 'cheetah'?

Tags: pronunciation

This question is prompted by [another question on Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40331/does-the-postfixed-%CF%87-in-jewish-greek-transliterations-simply-denote-the-aleph-i) regarding the addition of a last letter for no apparent reason during transliteration from Aramaic to Greek :

> We have the Aramaic given (חקל דמא haqel d'ma, field of blood) (Acts 1:18–19)—but again, with an otherwise **inexplicable χ attached to the end**: Ἁκελδαμάχ.

It made me wonder if an additional letter is being added during transliteration which might be regarded as a 'breathing' requirement for pronunciation.

And I therefore considered English as to whether we have 'breathing' letters at the end of words.

My question on BH is therefore :

Is the 'h' at the end of 'cheetah' merely there to indicate that the 'a' should be sounded as /ə/ rather than /eɪ/ ?

Comment: Yes @Jim  It is pronounced more like /ə/ as in an unstressed syllable., than /æ/ as in "bat". The other phoneme /eɪ/ is the "a" in "make".

Comment: Here are some [words ending in **-ah**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ah) but many are loan words, so the **h** make have some connection with the pronunciation in the original language — which may not have used the Latin alphabet.

Comment: [Relevant etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cheetah), but note that spelling is often arbitrary, especially with borrowings from other languages.

Comment: @WeatherVane How about words that end in -ta that are of Hindi extraction?

Comment: As the original comes from the [Hindi _chītā_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cheetah) , it might be best to wait for some of our freinds in India to reply...

Comment: @Mitch you mean their pronunciation? The same as words ending in **-ia**.

Comment: @WeatherVane We're trying to make some sort of theory about the '-ah' in 'cheetah', so we have to look at words with the same context. Lots of country names end in '-ia', also lots of spanish borrowings end in '-a'. So maybe it is something about hindi transcription. I'm leaning towards "It was just how that one guy spelled it". There's 'sutra', 'sofa', 'Vanita'... oh wait! 'purdah' has an '-ah'. 'Loofah'?

Comment: @Mitch I thought your comment said **-ia** not **-ta**. Perhaps the pronunciation of **verandah** in Hindi has a long **a** hence someone anglicised it with an **h** to indicate that.  I think Cascabel has the [idea](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494945/why-is-there-an-h-at-the-end-of-the-word-cheetah?noredirect=1#comment1194909_494945).

Comment: Your contribution of "words ending with _ah_" was great, and certainly seems to indicate the direction the answer should take. @WeatherVane As much as I would like to weigh in on this wonderful question, I will restrain myself and try to help any user with knowledge of Hindi  who answers this Q.

Comment: Interesting topic, but there is a simple answer to your very last mentioned explicit question "Is the 'h' at the end of 'cheetah' merely there to indicate that the 'a' should be regarded as the /ə/ as in comma, instead of the /eɪ/ as in make?". The answer is 'no' because most words in English ending in '-a' pronounce them as /ə/ also. I can't think of any word that pronounces word final 'a' as /eɪ/ . Where the word final 'h' comes from though is still interesting.

Comment: Also, re "It made me wonder if an additional letter is being added during transliteration which might be regarded as a 'breathing' requirement for pronunciation.": possibly it i an indication of such a pronunciation in a foreign language, but __in English there is no word final /h/.__

Comment: Reminds me of an attempt at a limerick by Anthony Burgess..."There was an old man from Anglia, who had an entangled ganglia..." Except that was as far as he could go, because there aren't many words ending in "gliah". @Mitch

Comment: Additionally, the Americans may be fans: Mariah, Oprah.

Comment: @Cascabel Are you saying 'Ojalá' is pronounced /o xa lax/ or /o xa lah/ with an explicit breath at the end? (modulo the vowels)

Comment: @Mitch Could we plz talk in IPA? Part of the problem is that DRAE does not provide a pronunciation key such as Oxford, or Cambridge for English.. Pronunciation in Spanish is pretty straightforward, and phonetic, so usually not specified.. The exceptions usually come from words of other _idiomas_. So, while most native speakers of Spanish would usually pronounce the word  "Ojalá" with a simple final  /a/,  there is also the issue of whether it is a central vowel, back allophone. or aspirated.

Comment: @Cascabel I thought I was (at least trying) to use IPA. The question was not about vowels but about the last phoneme of 'Ojalá'. Is it the vowel or is it an aspirate like /h/ or /x/? You seemed to imply that in general Spanish, it is the only word at all that ends in an glottal (or velar) aspirate.

Comment: @Mitch for me it feels more velar or possibly uvular aspiration than glottal,...but now that I am pronouncing it to the point that it no longer means anything....it is possible it is partly glottal. How do you pronounce Hanukkah?

Comment: Sorry if I seemed to insinuate that you were not using IPA correctly...my eyes get really bad by the end of the day..@Mitch Now that I think about it also possibly _reloj_..."two they are, and two shalt they be..."

Comment: As far as I know, some of the `ah` words in that list are pronounced with a long **a**: "chutzpah", "hoorah", "purdah" and possibly others. Perhaps others have the **a** shortened by usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way too long for a comment, but perhaps useful...

---

> [T]here are languages, such as Arabic, Malay, and Urdu, where /h/ can occur at the end of syllables, e.g., Malay *basah* /basah/ "wet". Notice that, in analysing syllable structure, we are talking about sounds (phonemes); the spelling is irrelevant. Thus, while many English words end in an *h* letter, this letter never represents an /h/ sound. It may be silent as in *messiah*, *cheetah*, or [...]

From: [*The Handbook of English Pronunciation* by Marnie Reed and John M. Levis](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118346952)

Note that bahasa Indonesia has [*citah*](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citah) for *cheetah*.

*Messiah* is interesting:

> The modern English form represents an attempt to make the word look more Hebrew, and dates from the [Geneva Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Bible) (1560).

From: [*Online Etymology Dictionary*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=messiah)

As can be seen at [TheFreeDictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ah), many, if not a clear majority of, English words ending in *ah* seem to originate from the Middle East or the Indian subcontinent or even further east. However, many more English words end in *a*. It seems that only words from those regions are likely to be transliterated to end in *ah*.

According to [*The Gem Set in Gold: Dhamma Chanting, English translation with Pāli & Hindi* by S. N. Goenka](https://store.pariyatti.org/mobile/Gem-Set-in-Gold-br-spanVipassanaspan_p_1457.html):

> **ḥ** is an aspiration following the vowel, e.g., **aḥ** is like 'uh'. [Hindi only, not Pāli. And the **ḥ** is also a vowel.]

---

So, here's a theory: It started with the spelling *Messiah* and then (English-speaking) people just started using that spelling for all kinds of words (with such aspirations, locally) from those regions.

If this would be true, it would be a nice connection to OP's other interest.